# Handle Dialogflow requests from multiple users through ngrok

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, ngrok

I'm working on a website for school, using Dialogflow, ReactJs and NodeJs. I am pretty new to doing this and I am not certain whether my implementation will work for my use case.

My website involves a game, which the server-side needs game state information from. I am sending requests from React to NodeJs as follows:

```js
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/game_state',
    data: {'current_player': current_player}
    // ... (more data is sent in reality)
  }
  );
```

My post requests are then handled by NodeJs as follows:

```js
app.post('/game_state',express.json(),(event)=>{
    current_player = event.body.current_player;
    // ... (more data)
});
```

This data can then be accessed by a Dialogflow request. For example, if the user asks: "Who's turn is it?", an intent with webhook fulfillment can then be triggered. The code for that:

```js
function turn(agent){
   current_player == 1 ? agent.add("Your turn") : agent.add("My turn");
}
```

As I said before, I am not very experienced with developing websites. I want to be able to use my implementation with multiple users at the same time, so one user's game states shouldn't influence those of another user.

So far, I've been using (the free version of) ngrok to test my website. My implementation works perfectly fine if only one user is accessing the link. However, when I open the website twice on the same computer (using the ngrok-generated link) and interact with e.g. the turn intent, I notice that the turn response will be the same for both even if for one session, it's the player's turn and for the other, it's the chatbot's turn.

Most likely, the post request is being overwritten given that the same link is used. I would like to find a solution that makes it possible to use the same link but have the server keep the game state information separate for each user. I feel like this might be possible with a user ID, but I'm stumped on how to implement that.

I know something like this may be an option:  `app.get("/game_state/:id", ...)`, but I am not sure how to also get this information to be available for the Dialogflow part of the implementation. Dialogflow calls the server itself, so it doesn't pass this user ID with it. Somehow, I'd need to distinguish it there as well.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you make Dialogflow detected intent API call at that time you are creating a session path

`const sessionPath = await sessionClient.projectAgentSessionPath(PROJECTID, sessionId);`

If you pass session Id  =  123456789A so for this Id Dialogflow managed all context and parameter on Id `123456789A`

`session Id  = USER`
when you get the webhook call to the server you also get this session Id or we also called UserId like

`let userId = agent.session.split('/')[4]`

you can find more information here
[dialogflow session](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/api-overview)